# How do I find out how long a Samsung Android device will be security supported?

Tags: samsung, security, ota-update

As we all know, surfing the Internet with a device that no longer gets security updates is a sure recipe for getting hacked.

- If I have a Samsung Android device, how do I find out whether it is still officially "security supported" (i.e., whether Samsung will push an OTA update when a security vulnerability is discovered) or not?
- If I consider buying a new Samsung Android device, where can I look up *how long* it will be security supported by Samsung?

*(I don't care about feature or OS version upgrades; this question is only about security updates. In addition, let's keep things simple and restrict this question to devices without a carrier lock - I know that carriers can delay updates, making matters even more complicated. I am looking for something [like this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) for Samsung Android devices.)*

Comment: lol... unless you have a Pixel/Nexus device, it is purely a crap shoot and there are no official, published guidelines... Just talking Samsung devices here it varies an incredible amount, usually by the cost of the device and the risk to security. The more expensive the device the longer you will get security updates, Galaxy S# devices seem to get them the longest, where the $100 prepaid models get few, if any, updates. If a major security hole is found, any device might get a random security update if not patching it would cost the company more money or reputation.

Comment: It's complex.. There is no clear policy. See this https://www.sammobile.com/2016/12/08/samsung-update-policy-improving/

Comment: Must say that statement "surfing the Internet with a device that no longer gets security updates is a sure recipe for getting hacked" is wrong on so many levels, for example since year ago I was using device on jellybean and guess what I didn't get hacked or have any malware on it

Comment: @Једноруки Крстивоје: ...at least none that you know of. ;-) No, seriously, there is [consensus among many security experts](https://security.googleblog.com/2015/07/new-research-comparing-how-security.html?m=1) that installing security updates is the single most important thing to protect your device online. You don't need to believe me, ask the guys at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Heinzi yes, it is important, but no necessarily, no kind of protection can prevent you from entering passwords, credit cards info where it shouldn't be entered, unless you use your own brain, also any malware can't work unnoticed. You have to use your brain while you are online, you can't eve be 100% protected by security level patches, I'm not saying anyone is stupid but you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје: I get what you are saying, but I still have to disagree: Professional malware *can* be extremely hard to detect, and the dangerous thing about unpatched security holes is that you can be pwned *even if* you are the worlds most security aware user and never fall for any phishing attempts. And these are not just theoretical threats, as the Snowden papers and the recent waves of ransomware have shown.

Comment: Professional malware like one you described maybe exist but nobody would risk leting it out in the wild in that case it would be discovered pretty fast, that kind of malware is used to targer one person or small group, so unless you are someone very important you don't have to worry that much. Well since you talking about Snowden that is what are we aware of if there is new method for them we will not know unless someone else blow the whistle. Also privacy and security can't exist at same time. There is no privacy online if you want it, don't use internet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, like most Android phone manufacturers, Samsung does not give any guarantees about future security updates.

They do, however, have a web page telling you which models are *currently* scheduled for monthly or quarterly security updates:

- [Samsung Mobile Security - Android Security Updates](https://security.samsungmobile.com/workScope.smsb)

Judging from the current (2017-10) content of the list, it appears that the duration and timeliness of security updates depends on the price of the phone: The 2015 flagship model S6 still gets monthly updates, whereas cheaper models, even those released in 2017, only receive quarterly updates.